# The loop i tried to make won't loop correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, numbers, countdowntimer

I tried to make a timer by making a function, that should keep on running until it hit 0. I thought I could get it to loop, but I think  it ended up skipping the first part of else
 "(int(time) - int(1))" and just repeating the second numeral it got after - 1. 
**What i want it to do:** Take the whole function and run it through until it reaches 0.
**What it does:** takes time -1 and keeps printing that until it reaches maximum recursion depth.

```
import time as tm

def Timer(time):
    if time == '0':
        print("done")
        tm.sleep(3)
    else:
        print(int(time) - int(1))
        Timer(time)
Timer(time)
```

Comment: You missed the arg which initialises the timer: `def Timer(time)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some small alterations on your code. Though it's very similar, I fixed the missing parameter and removed all the variable type convertions, since it didn't seem necessarry. Here's what I created (of course, you may have to adapt the function calling and probably remove my input):

```
import time as tm

def Timer(time):

    while (time>0):

        tm.sleep(1)
        time -= 1
        print(time)

    print("done")
    tm.sleep(3)

time=int(input('Choose your time value: '))
Timer(time)
```

Comment: In the example, you gave it just prints the numbers instead of waiting a second and the printing the next number.

Comment: Here, fixed and improved

Answer (score 2):

Assuming time is not a global, you need to pass time as input into your function and modify it accordingly so that you will eventually reach your recursive base case of `time == '0'`. Currently you are just calling `Timer()` over and over without changing the time, so you are going to keep recursively calling `Timer()` until you reach maximum recursion depth as you indicated (printing the changed time is not actually changing the time).

```
import time as tm

def Timer(time):
    if time == '0':
        print("done")
    else:
        print(int(time) - 1)
        tm.sleep(1)
        time = str(int(time) - 1)
        Timer(time)
Timer('4')
```

Comment: This fixed the problem with it repeating the same number but introduced a new problem where it would add 1 and then begin the countdown eg. (2, 3, 2, 1, 0, done)

Comment: Did you use the code exactly as is? I am not getting the issue you are describing with the above code. The `time` value is not incremented anywhere in this example.

Comment: found the mistake with what I had written but this still just prints till it reaches 0 instead of counting down in seconds.

Comment: If you want the code to do that, move the `tm.sleep(3)` from the `if` to the `else` statement, and use `1` as the argument. I edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
def Timer(time):
    for i in range(time,0, -1):
        print(time -1)
    print("done")


Timer(10)
```

If you really want a timer, look at importing time and use time.sleep(10)

```
from time import time
def Timer(time):
    for i in range(time,0, -1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(time - 1)
    print("done")


Timer(10)
```

Comment: The solutions you gave would only work if the timer was for 10 seconds. Since mine was made to give you a choice of how long it should run this didn't quite work,

Comment: Im sorry, but I disagree. It is not even for 10 seconds, as 0 is an int and not time. The code works, it counts down from whatever number you give it as a parameter to Timer(). I will add modified code to be an actual timer.